# Using ICE in Angular 10

Tags: angular, ice

I'm trying to use zeroC ICE in my Angular 10 application.
Just created a simple helloworld Angular app and installed ice with "npm install ice"
Then I invoke "Ice.initialise()" but I receive the following error:

```
ModuleRegistry.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: m.require is not a function
    at ModuleRegistry.js:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Function.require (ModuleRegistry.js:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Ice.js:7)
    at Object../node_modules/ice/src/Ice/Ice.js (Ice.js:45)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Object../node_modules/ice/src/index.js (index.js:5)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:109)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
```

Comment: if this is a browser application you should include the `node_modules/ice/lib/Ice.js` or directly include it from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ice/3.7.4/Ice.js

Comment: @José I've tried to add node_modules/ice/lib/Ice.js to the angular.json Script section...but I've got the same issue :/

Comment: mmm node_modules/ice/src/Ice/Ice.js (Ice.js:45) is part of the Node.js module, you must use one or the other not both, if you get the same error is because you are still including the node module

Comment: @José maybe my lack of skills in Angular...but can't figure out how to do that. You mean to not install the ICE package with npm and just including the Ice.js script. But then my problem is...how to  obtain the Ice object in my typescript file :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the same question on ICE git.

Basically you need to:

- update the project to include the browser version of Ice library.
- update the build to use a custom webpack configuration, this requires @angular-builders/custom-webpack.
- In the custom webpack configuration set ice as an external module so that the imports not result in build the node version.

And here is the detailed solution:

https://github.com/zeroc-ice/ice/issues/1039

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.